# How can i move words around in a sentence using regex?

Tags: regex, replace, words

So i have the following sentence: "How quickly daft jumping zebras vex."
and i need to come up with a single regex expression that will transform that sentence into this: 
"vex zebras jumping daft quickly How."
Can anyone please help me figure this out?

Comment: I don't think it is possible, unless the number of words in the sentences is limited.

Comment: Split the string into an array on `\s`, then reconstruct it by reading the array in reverse. Don't do it with RegEx (if it's even possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, regex is not meant for this, since it can't be known how many words there will be. But with your limited example, this works:

```
^(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\.$
```

Replace with

```
$6 $5 $4 $3 $2 $1.
```

Try it (press [Java]):  http://fiddle.re/67kef