# Moving specific words around in a sentence

Tags: regex, replace, move, words

Hi I have a long list of french words with (m) or (f) etc after the end of the word, is there any way I can move the '(m)' to before the word, I know how to change it after that's done to un or one etc using regular expressions but being quite new I'm not sure how to move it in the way I need to. I've looked at

[How can i move words around in a sentence using regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21532726/how-can-i-move-words-around-in-a-sentence-using-regex)

and have tried to modify it to my needs but i'm really lost, can anyone help me out please?

For example how would I get

anniversaire (m)

To become

(m) anniversaire

Comment: please post what you have tried and what language/how you are attempting to use regex, otherwise it is very hard to help you out

Answer (score 0):

This works for your needs

```
\b(.+) (\(m\))
```

And substitute with

```
$2 $1
```

Basically gets a word boundary, then starts a capturing group capturing anything up to a space, then a space, then a capturing group that takes the (m).  he substitution reverses those capture groups and puts a space in between them.

Comment: To make it more robust matching `(f)` and all kinds of whitespaces I modified your regex like this. `\b(.+)\s(\n?\(m\)|\(f\))`

Comment: I didn't think the OP wanted to match `(f)` so I left it out but thanks for the improvements

Comment: Read the first line of his question. He showed (m) just for example.

Comment: Thank you so much to both RedLaser and noob, Noob's method is more convenient for my needs but thank you both for your contributions. Just another thing, is there anyway to do the same thing to (m/f) instead of (m) or will I have to do that manually

Comment: @E.Sharp you can change it to `[mf]` instead of `m`.  This allows capture of anything in the square brackets